# conemu - on startup open two windows and position them like i want

Tags: conemu

I don't know if that's possible.

I managed to have conemu open two tabs (with a custom name) on startup and cd inside the folders i needs, now my question is:
Is there any way to make conemu open two different tabs in two different windows and position them top-right-corner and bottom-right-corner?

The task i run on startup is the following:

> title Website & cmd /k "%ConEmuDir%..\init.bat" && cd c:\src\www
>
> title Other& cmd /k "%ConEmuDir%..\init.bat" && cd c:\src\other

Thanks

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://conemu.github.io/en/NewConsole.html) and use `-new_console`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always, [read the documentation](https://conemu.github.io/en/ConEmuArgs.html).
Use `-new_console` to open a separate window, play with tabs normally. [Documentation](https://conemu.github.io/en/NewConsole.html).

If you’re lucky, the author of ConEmu will notice you and help you out better than I can.

Comment: i cannot use new-console (it does nothing)
I did read the documentation i tried the examples provided (which is something like this -new_console:s50H), but none worked. I also cannot use -cur_console:s1TVn as it throws a fatal error and crashed the application, that's why i was wonder if you knew a better way before asking on github (cause i think it is meant to be mainly for bugs and not really how-tos)

Comment: There are plenty of information. Here on SU and in [docs](https://conemu.github.io/en/SplitScreen.html). I think there is nothing to add.

Answer (score 0):

just for reference, in case this might help somebody.

i am using Cmder which builds on ConEmu, and in its setup screen (essentialy a ConEmu settings screen) i succeeded in making a new task that opens a cmd prompt and a Git bash prompt in a window split horizontally in the middle. You write the commands to start each shell one under another in the right bottom window. i.e. `cmd -cur_console:fn` is one command and `set "PATH..." & git-cmd.exe ...` is another. I copied the git-cmd.exe command from the corresponding Task

[image: cmder two panel split example config]

an example in ConEmu help page (e.g. as in `...cmder_mini\vendor\conemu-maximus5\ConEmu.exe /?`) states that the equivalent of the above Task, if one wanted to start it e.g. from a Windows Shortcut Properties dialog (in Target edit box) would be :
`ConEmu.exe -runlist cmd -cur_console:fn ||| git-cmd.exe ... -cur:console:s1THn` - but this command would fail when run from Windows CMD because pipes would have to be escaped, as helpfully stated [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1448931/conemu-runlist-commands).